# PySpark - read csv skip own header

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the problem that i can't skip my own Header in a CSV-File while reading it with Pyspark `read.csv`.
CSV-File looks like that:

```
°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°
°      My Header       °
°    Important Data    °
°        Data          °
°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°

MYROW;SECONDROW;THIRDROW
290;6848;66484
96849684;68463;63848
84646;6484;98718
```

I can't figure it out how i skip all those first lines or 'n' lines.
I tried something like:

```
    df_read = spark.read.csv('MyCSV-File.csv', sep=';') \
        .rdd.zipWithIndex() \
        .filter(lambda x: x[1] > 6) \
        .map(lambda x: x[0]) \
        .toDF('MYROW','SECONDROW','THIRDROW')
```

Is there any posibility to skip the lines, in particular how fast will it be? Data could be some GB's.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add filter on first lines:

```py
.filter(lambda line: not line.startswith("°"))
```

Another option is to mark those line as comments:

```py
.option("comment", "°")
```